# form search by a Users tag_id located in another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, checkbox, parameters, model-associations

I have a Many to Many association with Users and Tags. I want to show users based on the tag checkboxes that are selected.  Here is my search form in the view.

```
<%= form_tag users_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <% @tags.each do |tags| %>
      <li><%= check_box_tag "tag_id[]", tags.id %>
          <%= tags.name %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>

  <% end %>
```

When I click a couple boxes, it stores those in the "tag_id". My params looks like this:

```
 params
=> {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "tag_id"=>["1", "3"],
 "commit"=>"Search",
 "action"=>"index",
 "controller"=>"users"}
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to search in the controller. I need something like this:

```
def index
#psuedo code -- if searching#
 @users = User.all.where(#all users that have the selected tag_id's associated with the User. In this example, all users with tag_id's 1 and 3)
else
 @tags = Tag.all
 @users = User.all

end
```

my pitiful attempts:

```
def index
 binding.pry
 @tags = Tag.all
 @users = User.all.where(self.tags)
 #@users = User.search(params[:search])
end
```

Comment: What version of Rails are you using ? 4 or before?

Comment: I am using Rails 4.0.0

Comment: You want to select all users with both the tags, tag 1 and tag 3 or either of them will do?

Comment: @KirtiThorat   It is dynamic. It depends on what checkboxes the app user decides to click on. If the user clicks on checkboxes 1 and 3, I want all users with the first, and third tags to be found and displayed. If the app user only clicks on the 2nd checkbox, I want users associated with the 2nd tag to be displayed. Sorry, It's sometimes difficult to articulate what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I don't think you got my question. If user chooses 1 and 3 then do you want to show all users with tags 1 AND 3(both mandatory) or you want to show all users with tags 1 OR 3?

Comment: HE is trying to do a OR and not a AND :)
The more tag you click on, the more users you will see

Comment: Oh wow. You are right, my apologies. I am wanting it to display only the users with both tags 1 AND 3.  Sorry your original question made perfect sense now that I read it again

Comment: Nope, sorry Oxynum, it's the opposite. I'm looking for the users that have BOTH, or ALL the tags that are selected to narrow down the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer may require you to change quite a bit of stuff, but why struggle with this when there is a Gem you can use to do most, if not all, of what you are trying to do? Here's a Rails Cast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging?view=asciicast

Use this Gem: Acts-as-taggable-on

https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on

The only thing I haven't figured out yet is multiple tags but this should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your view is fine I think :) 
Try that :

```
def index
  @users = User.all(joins: :tags, conditions: {tags: {id: params.slice(:tag_id)}})
end

def index
  @users = User.includes(:tags).where('tags.id IN ?', params[:tag_id])
end
```

If the first one does not work, the second one should u_u, but I was quite sure of the first one.

Comment: Strong parameters are used for permitting attributes which can be used to create/update a record. You don't need them for firing a select query.

Comment: Thank you for this comment, you just opened my eyes :). I was wondering why I get the error sometimes or not, now its really logical!

Comment: @Oxynum  By following the at.users = User.where(params.slice(:tag_id)) I get this error:  SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.tag_id:    Thank you for the effort though :) Super appreciated.

Comment: Cool I'm gonna try that. By the way, I do have to edit my index to something using an if/else statement since the original index has all the users, then hitting the search narrows it down, but it should work still when it gets to where it works.

Comment: I'm probably screwing up my code somewhere.  The most recent edit gives me all the users, but when I hit a checkbox and hit search everything is deleted. I'm binding.pry'ing it to see because I think we are closer.

Comment: I updated again but it's weird my first proposition does not work

Comment: Sad day :'(   It's not working. It is saying no such table: 3: I'm sure this is really close. I'll post the answer when I get it figured out. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Yes there is a join table: user_tags